# Is there any way I can convert my java code to kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I found the code for hiding notification bar but I need it in kotlin. Can any one please help.

````
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        try {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } ```
````

Comment: Android Studio will offer to convert the Java code to Kotlin for you, such as when you paste a Java snippet into a Kotlin source file. In this case, the code should work pretty much as-is, except for `Exception e` turning into `e: Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ IDE you can simply right click on the java file and click :

`Convert Java File to Kotlin File` OR Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

Comment: Can I convert kotlin to java?

Comment: yes, just use intelliJ Idea and follow the instruction I gave